# Passing parameters from java to html to create google chart

Tags: java, html, spring, hashmap

There are four query values which I want to put in google chart **value1 to value4**. The problem is passing values from java to html. Under below I posted relevant codes.

Those

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  google.charts.load("current", {packages:["corechart"]});
  google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
  function drawChart() {


    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['Task', 'Hours per Day'],
      ['value1', **3**],
      ['value2', **2**],
      ['value3', **2**],
      ['value4', **2**]
    ]);

    var options = {
      title: 'My Daily Activities',
      pieHole: 0.4,
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('donutchart'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
  }
</script>
```

And this is java class.

```
    public ResponseEntity<Map<String,Object>> status() {
    Map<String,Object> map = new HashMap<String,Object>();

    long countByXmlSuccessResult = statusRepository.countByXmlSuccessResult();
    long countByXmlErrorResult = statusRepository.countByXmlErrorResult();
    long countByJsonSuccessResult = statusRepository.countByJsonSuccessResult();
    long countByJsonErrorResult = statusRepository.countByJsonErrorResult();

    map.put("xml success:", **countByXmlSuccessResult**);
    map.put("xml error:", **countByXmlErrorResult**);
    map.put("json success:", **countByJsonSuccessResult**);
    map.put("json error:", **countByJsonErrorResult**);


    return new ResponseEntity<Map<String,Object>>(map, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

plus, html file path is under src/main/java folder and java file path is under src/main/resources folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can expose that Java functionality as a service, and then make an ajax call to that service using jquery and finally grab the result and use it in your google chart code.
Ex:
Spring Boot:

```
@RestController
public class myHomeController{
   ...
   @RequestMapping("/getValues")
   public someDomainClass getMyValues(){
      ...
      //someDomainClass is just a reg. pojo to store your values.
      someDominClass class1 = new someDomainClass(value1, value2, value3
       , value4);
      return class1;
   }
}
```

Your HTML file:

```
 ...
<script>
   $.ajax({
      url: "/getValues",
      type: "GET",
      success: function(result){
          //result is a json object containing your values 1..4.
      },
      failure: functtion(err){...}
   });
</script>
```

Best of luck :)